# Установка PyQt5 через conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, conda

Сначала устанавливаю SIP командой `conda install sip`, все проходит успешно
Потом пытаюсь установить сам PyQt5, прописываю `conda install PyQt5`, на что он мне отвечает:

> Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: pyqt5
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
> pyqt
> ```
>
> You can search for this package on anaconda.org with
>
> ```
> anaconda search -t conda pyqt5
> ```
>
> You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with
>
> ```
> conda install anaconda-client
> ```

**UPD:** Смог ее установить введя команду `conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/mmcauliffe pyqt5`, но при выполнении любой программы с этой библиотекой появляется ошибка:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

Answer (score 1):

Через pip3 установи, он встроенный в python с 3.4 версии.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так еще можно. Тут, вроде, нет ошибок :)

conda install -c dsdale24 pyqt5

Answer (score 1):

Если до этого все установлено через conda, а вы попытаетесь установить через pip, могут слететь и другие пакеты! Они иногда конфликтуют. Только через conda

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте поставить через pip, если в конде на прямую его нет, то найдите в пепке где установлена anaconda в папке с python папку Scripts, там должен быть pip.exe или pip3.exe, если их нет то гуглите get-pip.py если есть, то зажимаете shift + правой кнопкой по папке - открыть окно комманд и пишите `pip.exe install pyqt5` или соответственно `pip3.exe install pyqt5`